# Angularjs - How to load views into a popup

Tags: angularjs

What's the best way to have my views appear in a popup modal?

I have the main dashboard of my app, and then whenever the user wants to add or edit an item on the dashboard I want this to be done via a form in a popup modal.

I know I can use jquery to handle the showing and hiding of the popup. But is there an angular way to do this, or is jquery acceptable in this scenario?

Comment: ngDialog is a great little library that I found very useful

Answer (score 1):

Check this out and go down to the modal section.  This looks nice and clean.  There is an example of the html and javascript there for you.  Your view is a template and can be a html file or inline html inside the javascript.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Much like everything in Angular, there are a number of ways you could do this. Perhaps the most simple way would be to have the HTML of the modal be hidden by either `ng-show` or `ng-hide`in conjunction with `ng-mouseover`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually doing this right now and decided to use jquery ui for the modal.  Dragging and resizing is hard to do and my modal requires that.  I wrap the modal call in a directive so modal pops up onclick.  The mistake I made was using jquery append to add new html.  Don't do this.  Use template or templateUrl and then put that in your modal.  This will ensure all scope vars in your modal will communicate with your controllers.